# Deployment of Rails app on Windows, with Ruby MRI, connected to MSSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, tomcat, deployment, mri

I've been trying to go from using jRuby to Ruby MRI. Current setup for Deployment is Warbler + Tomcat. Since this needs Java implementation I need to find an alternative. I am having a hard time to find any comprehensive answer, so here I am.

Reason for needing to change from jRuby, is that I want to update Rails (currently on 4.2) and there is no gem compatibility to Rails 5+ with MSSQL afaik.

Any answers towards a possible deployment setup are highly appreciated :)

Ps. Heroku uses PostgreSQL, so probably not really an option

Comment: Does this not work? https://github.com/JesseChavez/activerecord-jdbc-adapter. It purports rails 5.0-7.0 and seems to be reasonably maintained.